# Loading DataGridView from Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, datagridview

I'm having problems loading a stored procedure into a DataGridView. I've searched for an answer, however my code looks similar to every answer I've found. The stored procedure runs in another DataGridView I've added where I included it as a fixed datasource. I'm new to C#. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVER-SQL1;Initial Catalog=OPSystem;Integrated Security=True");
        myConn.Open();
        SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand("spCustomers", myConn);
        myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(myCmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = da;

    }
```

Comment: What is this.iTManagementSystemDataSet? It doesn't seem to have been initialized here in the Form's Load event.

Comment: Sorry that was removed from my code, I've edited my post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't bind to a SqlDataAdapter. You need to bind to the DataTable.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVER-SQL1;Initial Catalog=OPSystem;Integrated Security=True");
        myConn.Open();
        SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand("spCustomers", myConn);
        myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(myCmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

For context, the **SqlDataAdapter**:

> Represents a set of data commands and a database connection that are
>   used to fill the DataSet and update a SQL Server database. This class
>   cannot be inherited.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Perfect thanks :) I didn't add the line dataGridView1.DataBind(); as I think this is only needed for web forms.

Comment: Great. I wasn't sure if it was a windows or web app.

Comment: Works perfectly.
How can I mange showing columns and headers in the gridview?

Comment: The docs go over it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/gridview-overview

Answer (score 1):

```
private BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVER-SQL1;Initial  Catalog=OPSystem;Integrated Security=True");
myConn.Open();
SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand("spCustomers", myConn);
myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(myCmd);
da.Fill(dt);
bindingSource1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

Try BindingSource